# Send a text with a UPS

Tags: sms, project, send

I did get a school project, for my project i need to send a  sms when the UPS goes on battery power. I searched like 2 or 3 days on the internet. I saw many things, like apcupd, powerchute, powertext and many other thins. Nothing helped me jet.
I use a smart UPS 3000.

I hope someone of you can help me !

Greetings,

**Pietrick.**

Comment: What is your problem and where did you get stuck exactly ?

Comment: The problem is: i cant find somting that will send a text for me when the UPS goes on battery power. I did get stuck when i start reading the same things. (sorry for my english)

Comment: And i hope if you guy's know somting that can help me.